# How to name incoming data?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

Let's say I call some API. The data to be sent is called `Request` and data to be returned is called `Response`:

```
var someResponse = client.Post(url, someRequest);
```

But how to call some processor data to be sent?

```
var processResult = await localLogicService.Process(WhatNameOrPrefix);
```

Comment: What are you processing? Names should be self documenting when possible so something descriptive that will explain what is being processed to the next person reading your code would be best. 
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/coding-guidelines/coding-style.md

Comment: Use a incremental integer or timestamp (or both).